How can I reload the HTML audio player cache every time I press a button?
I have a created wav file called in.wav that is made every time the user presses a button. However, the audio play does not recognize the new in.wav until after a random amount of time. I want the audio player to refresh and check if in.wav is different.
function display(textString,keyString,modeString,instrumentString, onSuccess) {
    // ajax allows the function to take place without having to refresh webpage
    $.ajax({
    // searches for string_return in app.py
    url: "string_return",
    data: {
        text_string: textString,
        key_string : keyString,
        mode_string : modeString,
        instrument_string : instrumentString
        },
        // allows function know to return json data type and look for GET method
    dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        // what this does is if the ajax request is successful, it executes the specified function in
        // the parameter (in the below case, that's specified as function(returnedString))
    success: function(response) {
        onSuccess(response);
    }
    });
}
// if button with id "convert-button" is clicked...
$("#convert-button").on("click", function() {
    // textString is set to the value the user inputted in the text box
    let textString = $("#text-input").val();
    let key = $("#key").val();
    let mode = $("#mode").val();
    let inst = $("#instrument").val();
    // display method from above is called
    display(textString, key, mode, inst,function(returnedString) {
        $("#returned_string").text(returnedString);
    });

    const audio_player = document.getElementById("player");
        audio_player.load();
});

I know the audio player has reloaded when I get
10.245.100.65 - - [27/Apr/2024 17:13:01] "GET /static/in.wav HTTP/1.1" 206 - in my flask app. So again, how can I trigger this audio player reload?
I tried to implement the .load() function but it dont think it works it would not reload the new audio file.

"I have a created wav file called in.wav that is made every time the user presses a button" - The users are the ones creating the in.wav file? And you want to reload that file into #player, and make it play the changed file? If that's the case, please see this SO answer.
